# What is Refs column on varnishadm backend.list command?

Tags: load-balancing, varnish

Below is a command output example:

```
varnish> backend.list
200
Backend name                   Refs   Admin      Probe
webserver01(172.31.30.167,,80) 7      probe      Healthy 6/6
webserver02(172.31.24.128,,80) 11     probe      Healthy 6/6
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that it's the number of references to that backend (e.g. `set req.backend = foo`) from within the VCL.

Comment: But he counts this reference while the connection is open?